# MySql Кол-во дней в диапазоне дат

Tags: mysql, sql

Имеется таблица с диапазоном дат, так-же имеется таблица в которую вносятся "рабочие" дни (указывается день недели)

Как можно посчитать кол-во "рабочих" дней за диапазон дат?

К примеру человек поставил диапазон с 13.07.2015 по 22.07.2015 (включительно), указал, что он будет работать каждый понедельник и среду.

Результат рабочих дней должен равняться 4 т.к. понедельник и среда встречаются по 2 раза.

Подскажите, как реализовать запрос к БД?

Comment: Можно, конечно, при добавлении рабочего дня - забить программно табличку датами (генерировать на php из дней недели), но если человек укажет диапазон на 5499 год - кажется, будет многовато данных =)

Comment: Странности какие то написаны. Может под update добавите описание задачи?

Comment: Человек может создать "событие", указать ему с какое и по какое число оно идет, выбрать дни недели и время в которое это событие проводится. Мне необходимо сделать вывод всех событий по дням. Реализую "пагинатор" в виде "бесконечной ленты", для него нужно знать кол-во элементов для каждого дня т.к. там пагинатор в пагинаторе =)

Comment: В такой постановке задача плохо ложится в SQL. Вот если вы придете к необходимости отмечать фактические рабочие смены (т.е. с любыми отклонениями от "теории"), тогда у вас появится таблица где каждая дата это отдельная запись и число рабочих дней будет вычиясляться как `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sched WHERE wdate BETHWEEN :d1 AND :d2`

Comment: вот забавная конструкция (не уверен в её работоспособности) http://stackoverflow.com/q/18460158/4827341

Answer (score 1):

в таблице `dni` — отобранные дни недели (0 - понедельник, 1 - вторник и т.д.).

в таблице `period` — 30 примеров промежутков времени (начальный день — входит в подсчёт, конечный — не входит).

в итоговом запросе — количество понедельников и пятниц между датами.

функция, производящая подсчёт, вероятно, может быть ещё упрощена:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4b676d/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table dni (id int, d int);

create table period (id int, s date, p date);

insert into dni values
   (1, 0) # пн
  ,(1, 4) # пт
;

insert into period values
  (1, '2015-01-01', '2015-01-02')
  ,(1, '2015-01-01', '2015-01-03')
  ,(1, '2015-01-01', '2015-01-04')
  ,(1, '2015-01-01', '2015-01-05')
  ,(1, '2015-01-01', '2015-01-06')
  ,(1, '2015-01-01', '2015-01-07')
  ,(1, '2015-01-01', '2015-01-08')
  ,(1, '2015-01-01', '2015-01-09')
  ,(1, '2015-01-01', '2015-01-10')
  ,(1, '2015-01-01', '2015-01-11')
  ,(1, '2015-01-01', '2015-01-12')
  ,(1, '2015-01-01', '2015-01-13')
  ,(1, '2015-01-01', '2015-01-14')
  ,(1, '2015-01-01', '2015-01-15')
  ,(1, '2015-01-01', '2015-01-16')
  ,(1, '2015-01-01', '2015-01-17')
  ,(1, '2015-01-01', '2015-01-18')
  ,(1, '2015-01-01', '2015-01-19')
  ,(1, '2015-01-01', '2015-01-20')
  ,(1, '2015-01-01', '2015-01-21')
  ,(1, '2015-01-01', '2015-01-22')
  ,(1, '2015-01-01', '2015-01-23')
  ,(1, '2015-01-01', '2015-01-24')
  ,(1, '2015-01-01', '2015-01-25')
  ,(1, '2015-01-01', '2015-01-26')
  ,(1, '2015-01-01', '2015-01-27')
  ,(1, '2015-01-01', '2015-01-28')
  ,(1, '2015-01-01', '2015-01-29')
  ,(1, '2015-01-01', '2015-01-30')
  ,(1, '2015-01-01', '2015-01-31')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select
  date_format(s,'%Y-%m-%d, %a') as 'начало',
  date_format(p,'%Y-%m-%d, %a') as 'конец',
  sum(
    ceil((p-s)/7)-1+
    if((weekday(p)>weekday(s)
        and (weekday(s)<=d and weekday(p)>d))
       or (weekday(p)<=weekday(s)
           and (weekday(s)<=d or weekday(p)>d)),
      1,0)
  ) as 'дней'
from period, dni
group by s, p
order by s, p
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4b676d/1/0)**:

```
|          начало |           конец | дней |
|-----------------|-----------------|------|
| 2015-01-01, Thu | 2015-01-02, Fri |    0 |
| 2015-01-01, Thu | 2015-01-03, Sat |    1 |
| 2015-01-01, Thu | 2015-01-04, Sun |    1 |
| 2015-01-01, Thu | 2015-01-05, Mon |    1 |
| 2015-01-01, Thu | 2015-01-06, Tue |    2 |
| 2015-01-01, Thu | 2015-01-07, Wed |    2 |
| 2015-01-01, Thu | 2015-01-08, Thu |    2 |
| 2015-01-01, Thu | 2015-01-09, Fri |    2 |
| 2015-01-01, Thu | 2015-01-10, Sat |    3 |
| 2015-01-01, Thu | 2015-01-11, Sun |    3 |
| 2015-01-01, Thu | 2015-01-12, Mon |    3 |
| 2015-01-01, Thu | 2015-01-13, Tue |    4 |
| 2015-01-01, Thu | 2015-01-14, Wed |    4 |
| 2015-01-01, Thu | 2015-01-15, Thu |    4 |
| 2015-01-01, Thu | 2015-01-16, Fri |    4 |
| 2015-01-01, Thu | 2015-01-17, Sat |    5 |
| 2015-01-01, Thu | 2015-01-18, Sun |    5 |
| 2015-01-01, Thu | 2015-01-19, Mon |    5 |
| 2015-01-01, Thu | 2015-01-20, Tue |    6 |
| 2015-01-01, Thu | 2015-01-21, Wed |    6 |
| 2015-01-01, Thu | 2015-01-22, Thu |    6 |
| 2015-01-01, Thu | 2015-01-23, Fri |    6 |
| 2015-01-01, Thu | 2015-01-24, Sat |    7 |
| 2015-01-01, Thu | 2015-01-25, Sun |    7 |
| 2015-01-01, Thu | 2015-01-26, Mon |    7 |
| 2015-01-01, Thu | 2015-01-27, Tue |    8 |
| 2015-01-01, Thu | 2015-01-28, Wed |    8 |
| 2015-01-01, Thu | 2015-01-29, Thu |    8 |
| 2015-01-01, Thu | 2015-01-30, Fri |    8 |
| 2015-01-01, Thu | 2015-01-31, Sat |    9 |
```

---

отказ от ответственности: связи между таблицами я не прописывал, как излишние для демонстрации работы функции.

Comment: | 2015-01-01, Thu | 2015-01-12, Mon |    3 |. Этот период содержит 2 пятницы и 2 понедельника. Граничные условия точно верные?

Comment: @Zufir, конечная дата **не входит** в диапазон, как и написано в ответе. не входит по чисто техническим причинам — дата, это, вообще-то ноль часов ноль минут ноль секунд указанного дня. и сам день в «дату» не входит.

Comment: Да, действительно, просмотрел. Извините. Просто привык, что "с-по" - это включительно.

Answer (score 0):

В два шага. В MSSQL я бы использовал рекурсирвную CTE, с MySQL дел имел очень мало, поэтому будет код по ссылкам из гугла.
1. Развернуть период в список дат: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295616/how-to-get-list-of-dates-between-two-dates-in-mysql-select-query
2. К списку дат приджойнить через [DayOfWeek](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek) вашу таблицу с рабочими днями.

Answer (score -1):

Настоящие герои всегда идут в обход ;) Пробуйте:

```
<?php
$d1 = new DateTime( '2015-07-13' );
$d2 = new DateTime( '2015-07-22' );
$dofw = array( 1, 3 ); // 0 - воскресенье
$sum = 0;
while ( $d1 <= $d2 )
{
    if ( in_array( $d1->format( 'w' ), $dofw ) )
        $sum++;
    $d1->modify( '+1 day' );
}
echo $sum, "\n";
```